# prepare(for segue:) not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have looked at relevant posts and I don't understand why this is not getting called in my ViewController.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    print("prepare in Start got triggered")

    if segue.destination is RegistrationViewController {

        let newVC = sender as? RegistrationViewController
        newVC?.testString = "Mission accomplished, passed this data"
    }

}
```

I call it from a button press

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegistrationFromStart", sender: self)
```

testString is a property in RegistrationViewController
the segue happens, no problem, but the property never changes and the prepare never triggers the print command.

I print testString in the viewDidLoad of RegistrationViewController

```
  print("RegistrationViewController testString \(testString)")
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How do you do the segue connection in the storyboard? It's from the ViewController or from the button?

Answer (score 0):

Simply this

```
let newVC = sender as? RegistrationViewController
newVC?.testString = "Mission accomplished, passed this data"
```

is invalid

as `sender` can't be casted to `RegistrationViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

  if let des = segue.destination as? RegistrationViewController {
      des.testString = "Mission accomplished, passed this data"
  }

}
```

your source of segue connection should be the VC itself not from any action , and inside an `IBAction` for example set

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegistrationFromStart", sender:nil)
```

Comment: That's all very nice, but it doesn't explain why `print("prepare in Start got triggered")` does not print, which is what the question asks.

Comment: following the correct thing will make it works with him , not necessarily the answer to be and explicit direct reason of the problem

Comment: OK, I think you're right and he's just asked the question badly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Thanks for pointing that out.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("prepare in Start got triggered")

    if segue.destination is RegistrationViewController {

        let newVC = segue.destination as? RegistrationViewController
        newVC?.testString = "Mission accomplished, passed this data"
    }

}
```

That said, it never fires the print statement but it does pass the data which was the whole point. 
And to your points, yes I'm calling it from an IBAction

```
 @IBAction func startKiosk(_ sender: Any) {
    clickSound?.play()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegistrationFromStart", sender: self)
 }
```